# R Markdown horizontal rule that will also work with LaTeX pdf?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am aware that `***` is Pandoc's Markdown for a horizontal rule. This horizontal line looks good on HTML, but if I knit my Markdown into a pdf the horizontal rule only runs half the width of the pdf, and it is centered. This combination just makes the horizontal rule look plain ugly.

How do I properly put a horizontal rule in my R Markdown that can render properly to both HTML and pdf? `Properly == full length/full width`. And while I'm at it, can I format the horizontal rule (color, thickness, etc.) without getting into much CSS which I know nothing about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a `tex` file, say `header.tex`, containing:

```
\let\oldrule=\rule
\renewcommand{\rule}[1]{\oldrule{\linewidth}}
```

Then in your `Rmd` file:

```
---
title: "test"
author: "Stéphane Laurent"
date: "30 mars 2018"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---
```

Comment: For formatting the line in html, I don't see how without using CSS. And this is another question.

Comment: ```Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 6, column 13
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load_utf8 -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution halted``` Tried this idea but got what you see as an error. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: You likely missed the colon after `pdf_document`.

Comment: That's exactly what I missed.

Comment: and this gets rid of the big space between the heading and the horizontal rule `\let\oldrule=\rule` `\renewcommand{\rule}[1]{\vspace{-25pt}\oldrule{\linewidth}}`

Comment: Is there a way to add this within the document, if I don't want to use a header file?