# R Markdown reduce space between heading and horizontal rule

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I wanted to create a horizontal rule that stretches the full width of a pdf, and also works in my HTML files that are knitted from R Markdown. I followed outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575945/r-markdown-horizontal-rule-that-will-also-work-with-latex-pdf/49576608#49576608), shown below, which worked very well.

A problem with the solution is that it creates a giant block of 'white space' between the heading and horizontal rule. How do I eliminate, or reduce the size, of this 'white space'?

Here is the method I used. Firstly, a `tex file` is made  called  `header.tex`, containing:

```
\let\oldrule=\rule
\renewcommand{\rule}[1]{\oldrule{\linewidth}}
```

Then in the `Rmd` file put:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---
```

And this is the result:

[image: space.png]

Comment: Can you add the link to the original answer you got from Stéphane Laurent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575945/r-markdown-horizontal-rule-that-will-also-work-with-latex-pdf/49576608#49576608

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remove Padding

If you want to remove the padding around the line, you can set a negative `vspace` command within the line definition as [shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230636/decrease-vertical-space-before-horizontal-line):

```
\let\oldrule=\rule
\renewcommand{\rule}[1]{\vspace{-25pt}\oldrule{\linewidth}}
```

And the .Rmd file:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---


# Title

Test

Test
```

[image]

### Underline Header

You are probably better off changing the styles of the header to include the underline as part of the `# Title` command. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69330/add-a-rule-after-chapter-title-using-titlesec) shows how it can be achieved in LaTeX

Firstly, the `header.tex` file becomes:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\let\oldrule=\rule
\renewcommand{\rule}[1]{\oldrule{\linewidth}}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
```

And a basic example. Note that `subparagraph: yes` is included, and without it the `titlesec` package cannot be used. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916124/not-able-to-use-titlesec-with-markdown-and-pandoc) for the explanation.

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
subparagraph: yes
---


# Title

Test

Test
```

[image]